# PHP code adding extra caracters to json string

Tags: php, json, string

So I am trying to POST a jsont string from my MacOS app to my server and than the server sends me that string in an email.
The php code looks like this:

```
<?php
$postVar = $_POST['data'];

if (!empty($postVar)) {
$to      = '<myemailaddress>';
$subject = 'data recieved';
$message = $postVar;
$headers = 'From: <someemailaddresshere>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

This recieves the data and returns a 200 response however the string sent to the server does not match the string sent in email.

Sample of string to server:

```
{
  "µTorrent" : {
    "isActive" : false
  },
  "Bear" : {
    "isActive" : false
  },
  "Terminal" : {
    "isActive" : false
  }
}
```

Sample of the string recieved in email:

```
{
  \"µTorrent\" : {
    \"isActive\" : false
  },
  \"Bear\" : {
    \"isActive\" : false
  },
  \"Terminal\" : {
    \"isActive\" : false
  }
}
```

Those backslashes are not supposed to be there, what could cause this problem?

Comment: Please check might you have applied `json_encode($your_post_array)` more than once.

Comment: Which PHP version do you use? May be some old (<5.4) with `magic quotes` switched on? (http://php.net/magicquotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backslash are added for security reason.
If you just want to remove backslash you can use stripslashes.

```
$message = stripslashes($postVar);
```

But I suggest to create an array of your data and the return json_encode of your array

Comment: Ok, so this fixes the problem, hovever the problem is with the swift code since the built in jsonserialization has a flaw that looks just like the magic quotes.

Comment: I don't know well about swift, but I found an example about json deserialization in swith there : https://www.raywenderlich.com/150322/swift-json-tutorial-2 
Hope it can help